# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am struggling with linq to get the datetime.

I am trying to get the info if the records are less than the current date

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult _Events()
{
          DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
          var   DocsFirst =(from t in db.tble_presentation
                            where dt >=  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.presentation_date)
                             select t).OrderByDescending(t => t.presentation_date).Take(2);

            return PartialView(new Newsmodel
            {
               DocsList_list1 = DocsFirst,
            });
}
```

but I get this following error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

thanks in advance
Hesh

Comment: exception tells DocsFirst is type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' and DocsList_list1 is 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'. Can you show how do you define and assign value into DocsList_list1 ?

Comment: This line may useful  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561784/7059557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `DocsList_List1` is of type `IOrderedEnumerable` (as @Emre points out in the comment). To make the code compile, you either have to change the declaration of `DocsList_list1` to be of a compatible type (probably `IEnumerable`) or make the result of the linq query an `IOrderedEnumerable`. An (somewhat ugly) way to do the latter:

```
var DocsFirst = (from t in db.tble_presentation
                 where dt >=  EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(t.presentation_date)
                 select t).Take(2).AsEnumerable()
                 .OrderByDescending(t => t.presentation_date);
```

It's somewhat ugly because it does the ordering in memory instead of letting the database do it, but it still only reads the two requested elements thanks to `Take(2)` being placed before  `AsEnumerable()`.